# Change name of country in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, country-regions

I tried for hours.. Even changed vendor files (from Zend framework).

How in this world can I change the country name "France", in address, to "France métropolitaine", in Magento 2?

I tried  i8n, database, vendor files ( Yes, it's bad, but still, does not work).
Of course, I did flush cache severa times, and even setup:upgrade / compile / content deploy.

Any tips would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this by changing name from locale file.

Go to app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/YOURTHEME/i18n

if your locale language is English (US), you will have a en_US.csv file in it. Then add a line with: United Kingdom, Great Britain

Comment: THanks for the help. LIke I said, i tried this (i18n), failure.

Comment: It should work, else first you need to check whether the local file is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- Locate your theme folder that would be inside app/design/frontend

Step 2:- Look for the i18n folder. Here you will find files such as en_UK or en_US depending upon your local language.

Step 3:- Edit the file and add the code as follows:- "your_current_country_name", "new_name". Please refer to the image below.

[image]

Comment: THanks for the help. LIke I said, i tried this (i18n), failure.